# Would there be a compelling reason for implementing integrity check in a file transfer protocol, if the channel uses TLS?

Tags: ssl, client-server, protocols, file-transfer

I am developing a client server pair of applications to transfer files by streaming bytes over TCP/IP and the channel would use TLS always.

(Note: Due to certain OS related limitations SFTP or other such secure file transfer protocols cannot be used)

The application level protocol involves minimum but sufficient features to get the file to the other side.

I need to decide if the application level protocol needs to implement an integrity check (Ex: MD5).
Since TLS guarantees integrity, would this be redundant?

Answer (score 0):

The use of TLS can provide you with some confidence that the data has not been changed (intentionally or otherwise) *in transit*, but not necessarily that the file that you intended to send is identical to the one that you receive.

There are plenty of other opportunities for the file to be corrupted/truncated/modified (such as when it's being read from the disk/database by the sender, or when it's written to disk by the receiver). Implementing your own integrity checking would help protect against those cases.

In terms of how you do the checking, if you're worried about malicious tampering then you should be checking a cryptographic signature (using something like GPG), rather than just a hash of the file. If you're going to use a hash then it's generally recommended to use a more modern algorithm such as a SHA-256 rather than the (legacy) MD5 algorithm - although most of the issues with MD5 won't affect you if you're only concerned about accidental corruption.